# Google Earth Conversion Misalignment

Tags: google-earth, google-maps-api

I'm seeing a small error (~0.5m) in the display of KML in Google Earth and I'm trying to figure out where the error lies.

My app can import from, and export to, KML, via the Google Maps API. I import a Google image, draw a line on it, then export it to KML. When I view the KML in Google Earth the line is visually misaligned to the image from where I drew it in my app.

In my app the UTM coordinates of the line are:

P1: x = 416619.30 m, y = 3847357.66 m
P2: x = 416559.27 m, y = 3847383.44 m

Translating to KML (input):

-105.911133431393,34.7649696951135,0
  -105.911791778749,34.7651972543985,0

If I subsequently export the line feature from Google Earth it has the same coordinates:

-105.911133431393,34.7649696951135,0 -105.911791778749,34.7651972543985,0

If I then add two placemarks in Google Earth using my exact UTM coordinates (GE in UTM mode) they appear visually to be in the correct spots. However, if I export those features they now have these coordinates:

Start -105.9111365898891,34.76496376445177,0
End -105.9117947377592,34.76519328944141,0

I do note that Google Earth only appears to retain UTM to 1m accuracy and quantises manually placed placemark as such. Might this be the root of the issue? Otherwise, is Google Earth using a different UTM<->WGS84 conversion than me? (seems unlikely!)